# PHP Variable being lost in the file

Tags: php, variables

I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious here... I'm trying to figure out why it seems like PHP variables are being "lost" in the same file. The code of my project can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/3i4p8hKg).

Basically I dumbed it down to declaring a simple variable at line 27 and at line 120 I pull it into $data. $data is stored in the created file and in every case, $i is null.

This is bizarre!

May someone please, please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "lost". Are you receiving errors? We need to see **specific** examples.

Comment: You're also using `$i` as the counter in a number of for loops. Try changing the name of the variable you're setting on line 27 and reading on line 120 to something you're not using elsewhere.

Comment: My worst nightmare would be that `here`

Comment: Please don't provide a link to code, include the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be writing PHP files in PHP. This is not just a bad idea, it's downright dangerous.
<del>(Self-writing code is the first step to the robot apocalypse!)</del>

The reason `$i` is null is because you are not passing the variable in any way. Just writing `$i` to a file doesn't magically make `$i` keep the value it had before.

Have a serious think about what <del>the hell</del> you're trying to do...

Comment: I `git merge`d your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't think that setting `$i` to `0` on line 71 is part of the issue? Or, maybe using it again in a `for` loop on line 112 is your problem? Actually, you're using it all over the place. I think you need to rename your 'special' variable to something more meaningful.

Nothing in programming is bizarre. Seriously.

<del>And don't paste your code in Pastebin, paste it on SO!</del>

Comment: I `git merge`d your answer :D